# scopes in javascript

Tags: javascript, scopes

I have a simpe object in javascript which has few methods..Two of them I want to periodicaly call with `window.setTimeout` functions. My current code looks like this.

```
var shakeResolver = function () {
 var resolveTimeout;
 console.log(this);
 var context = this;
 this.startShakeResolve = function () {
     this.resolveTimeout = window.setTimeout(this.call(context.stopShakeResolve, context), 2000);
     $(window)
         .on('devicemotion', this.onDeviceMotion);
 };

 this.onDeviceMotion = function (event) {};

 this.stopShakeResolve = function (context) {
     this.resolveTimeout = window.setTimeout(context.startShakeResolve, settings.interval);

 };

}
```

The problem is apparently in my misunderstanding how scopes are working, it looks like when calling the function from timeout, it is called from another context where it actually doesn't exist?

Comment: In the first call to `setTimeout`, you're executing a function immediately and actually passing its *return value* (which happens to be undefined) as the function to call after the timeout. (Edit: that is, of course, assuming that your use of `this.call` invokes the usual `Function.call` and not your own variation.)

Comment: What is `this`? Is it a function? How are you calling `shakeResolver`? To learn more about `this`, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified code: Scope of setTimeout is always `window` Object. you can Change context of function using `call` `apply` and `bind`(bind is not supported by older IE browsers IE <= 8 ).

```
var shakeResolver = function() {
    this.resolveTimeout;
    console.log(this);
    var context = this;
    this.startShakeResolve = function() {
        this.resolveTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
            context.stopShakeResolve.apply(context, arguments);
        }, 2000);

        $(window).on('devicemotion', function(){
                    context.onDeviceMotion.apply(context, arguments);
            });
    };

    this.onDeviceMotion = function(event) {
    };

    this.stopShakeResolve = function(context) {
        this.resolveTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
            context.startShakeResolve.apply(context, arguments)
        }, settings.interval);

    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`call()` takes as first parameter the context which the function is called from. This means that your `this.call(context.stopShakeResolve, context)` makes your context be `context.stopShakeResolve` which means that when the function is called `this` is equivalent to `context.stopShakeResolve`.

Just to make it clearer:

```
this.stopShakeResolve = function (context) {
    this.resolveTimeout = window.setTimeout(context.startShakeResolve, settings.interval);
};
```

Does not have a function inside it called `shakeResolver` so it would throw an exception on you saying that it does not have property or method called this way. Change the call to the following:

```
this.stopShareResolve.call(this, context)
```